# Update (stock / non-rolling) CentOS

Tags: centos, updates, yum

Various hosts use various ISO installs for CentOS, one doesn't use rolling updates when they install. I ran the following immediately after signing in after a fresh install:

```
yum update
```

I received the following error:

> Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

What is the simplest method of getting CentOS updated from the command line?

---

> Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"

I edited `etc/resolv.conf` and edited in:

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>   nameserver 8.8.4.4

I still recieve the same problem from cURL.

Comment: try `yum check-update` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is economical: I can not waste hours and days on critical problems that simply shouldn't exist in any shipped operating system.

I've come to a definitive conclusion based on two critical points:

1. I have a choose of Linux operating systems so I'm not damned to *have* to work with CentOS.
2. This was the official ISO (granted from mirrors) but listed off of their official website. If I can't even install it from a USB drive without great difficulty and I can't manage to update the OS because it's default settings are broken then I can *not* imagine how much worse it will get.

Clearly there wasn't any serious testing done before releasing the operating system. I've got other choices of Linux distribution with the host so I'll test those out locally first.

That being said if someone *does* want to provide a *technical* answer it would be for other people's benefit, not mine. I do ask that if someone does post it to ensure to post a **dynamic** answer as it's widely known that Linux distributions change all the time so best to post an answer that will help more people for a longer period of time.